# how to keep unit conversions in boost::units in single-precision floats?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-units

I have aliases for radians and degrees that use float as the storage type.

When I convert between these two units I see the assembly promote the values to doubles and then back to floats when doing conversions.

**Q:** How can I make sure that all operations and conversions stay in floats?

My Code:

```
using radians_f = boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::plane_angle, float>;
using degrees_f = boost::units::quantity<boost::units::degree::plane_angle, float>;

degrees_f to_degrees(const radians_f& angle) { return static_cast<degrees_f>(angle); }
radians_f to_radians(const degrees_f& angle) { return static_cast<radians_f>(angle); }
```

From compiler explorer I see the following assembly instructions: https://godbolt.org/z/Gnjr54dn6

- **cvtss2sd** - Converts a single-precision floating-point value in the “convert-from” source operand to a double-precision floating-point value in the destination operand.
- **mulsd** - Multiplies the low double-precision floating-point value in the second source operand by the low double-precision floating-point value in the first source operand.
- **cvtsd2ss** - Converts a double-precision floating-point value in the “convert-from” source operand to a single-precision floating-point value

*PS: I would not be surprised if I have defined my aliases or/and my conversion functions incorrectly.*

Answer (score 1):

I found a hacky workaround (which I'm sure can be "productionized" by making Boost Units compute the 57.x degrees per radian constant) to avoid the conversions to and from `double`, but it really highlights the fact that Boost Units is causing another surprising sort of overhead: memory loads and stores which aren't necessary if you use `float` directly, or even your own wrapper for `float`.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/afPE7baxT

So while the above shows one (unrefined) way to force calculations to stay as floats, if your real question is "How do I avoid overhead" you're still a bit far from nirvana.

Comment: unfortunately using angles were the minimal reproducible example in the question of "How do I avoid overhead" since the problem applies to many other units that I need as well.

Comment: @CJCombrink: Yeah, what I'm saying is that it looks like avoiding (all) overhead might require ditching Boost Units, based on the demo I made above.

Comment: Having a destructor or a copy constructor in your wrapper can cause this suboptimality.